# What account should be used in the Power BI gateway configuration?

Tags: powerbi

I'm installing the Power BI gateway (standard) and it asks me to enter a user account (screenshot below).

What account should this be? Service principal? or an user account? What account should be used here so that there for example if the user leaves the organization then there won't be any issues?

[image]

Comment: You should use your work profile account for power Bi. Bcz its a busness intelligence tool you are not gonna use it for personal. But if you want to use it personal then you can use your personal user-account.

Comment: If I use my work profile, and I leave the job then what happens when my account is deactivated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What account should this be? Service principal? or an user account?

User account of a gateway admin.

> What account should be used here so that there for example if the user leaves the organization then there won't be any issues?

Add another gateway admin in the service.  The important thing is to retain and securely store in a shared location the Windows Admin account credentials (if non-domain-joined) and most importantly the gateway recovery key.

Comment: Should it be a mail enabled security group or an individual account? If the later then what happens when the user leaves?

Comment: Security groups are better, but not always possible.  In many organizations there are many gateways, and security group creation is locked-down.  If the only gateway admin leaves, a Power BI Administrator can add a new one.

Comment: Ok so after installing this account configurable in the windows app or in web portal?

Comment: Gateway users and admins are managed in the Power BI portal.

Comment: This question is about the account used when installing the gateway. Not the gateway admin or users.

Comment: That account will become the initial gateway admin, but has no other significance.